# Asp core package which can convert Markdown to PDF

Tags: pdf, c#, markdown

Are there any asp core package which can convert Markdown to PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion [.NET Core Word library](https://www.syncfusion.com/document-processing/word-framework/net-core/word-library) (DocIO) allows you to create, edit, modify, and convert Word documents. Using this, you can also convert Markdown to Word document and PDF.

Refer the below sample link for converting Markdown to PDF : [GitHub sample to convert Markdown to PDF](https://github.com/SyncfusionExamples/DocIO-Examples/tree/main/Word-to-PDF-Conversion/Convert-Markdown-to-PDF/.NET-Standard)

UG documentation: [Markdown to Word conversion, Word to PDF conversion](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/docio/convert-markdown-to-word-document-in-csharp)

Online demo: [Syncfusion .NET Core Word library - Online demos](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/DocIO/SalesInvoice?utm_source=github&utm_medium=listing&utm_campaign=github-docio-examples#/material)

Syncfusion offers a free community license also. https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Note: I work for Syncfusion